# When did the IBM 650 have a "Table lookup on Equal" instruction?

Tags: history, assembly, instruction-set, ibm650

In 1959, Donald Knuth wrote an assembly program named SuperSoap for the IBM 650. [Here](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2018/07/102784983-05-01-acc.pdf) is the manual, and [here](https://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2018/07/102784987-05-01-acc.pdf) is a listing of the program (in SuperSoap assembly language). Quoting from the abstract:

> SuperSoap is a major revision of Case SOAP III [Knuth's modifications to SOAP II], designed to take
> advantage of a 650 with extra attachments. The present SuperSoap program requires index registers, core, a disk file unit, and **the table-lookup-on-equal
> feature**.

Note the bolded text. Looking at the [available documentation on Bitsavers](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/650/), we know that the index registers and core come with the IBM 653, and the disk file unit is presumably an IBM 355. But **what is this mysterious "TLE"**?
Appendix I of the SuperSoap manual lists operation codes and mnemonics, assigning TLE to operation code 63. Available 650 documentation that lists instructions says that operation code 63 is unused. It does not seem to have been added when the Model 4 was released (see the last section, beginning on page 33, of [this document](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/650/650_System_Bulletins.pdf)).

Comment: Guess: Sometimes institutions (e.g. universities) had custom-made extensions for these early computers, and TLE may be one of them. Sometimes the custom-made extensions became mainstream.

Comment: @dirkt That may well be the case. Apparently Knuth's installation also had an extra set of console switches accessible as location 8004 (source: Knuth's article ["The IBM 650: An Appreciation from the Field"](https://www.computer.org/csdl/magazine/an/1986/01/man1986010050/13rRUB6SpU2); he mentions that the feature is unique as far as he is aware).

Comment: Note: The Knuth article I referred to in my previous comment is freely accessible [here](http://www.ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/KnuthIBM650Appreciation.pdf).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The TLE instruction is a modification of the TLU instruction.

**TLU (Table LookUp)** (Opcode 84) compared a word with a series of consecutive words on the drum and finished as soon as an entry was found being equal *or higher*. It was meant to find a point in a **sorted list**.

**TLE (Table Lookup Equal)** (Opcode 63) is a modification of TLU stopping only when equal, which is useful to find a known entry in an **unsorted list**.

TLE is essentially executing TLU, but suppressing assessment on higher. It was available from IBM as 'add on' at USD 25 per month, as mentioned on page 375 of the [BRL Report 1115](http://www.ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/BRL61-ibm065.html#IBM-650-RAMAC) of 1961.

Comment: Wow. [So it is](http://www.ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/BRL61-ibm065.html#IBM-650-RAMAC). Thanks; I didn't know that that publication even existed. Purchasing a single new instruction is an interesting concept. You wouldn't happen to know the specifics of the "modified branch on distributor", would you? Presumably an alteration of operations codes 90..99 (I hope).

Comment: Ah ja, Ed's site is grea - and so is he. Maybe just ask him. Say a hello from Hans. I do not have much knowledge about the 650. My era starts with the /360 :) Just happen to have a few books shelfed - and all these third party comparison lists are among the most useful. Selling add on instructions are a core business for IBM until today. IMHO the whole reason why the term CISC exists :))

Comment: Yeah on second thought it isn't unusual. But I do like the idea of paying $25 to have a technician install probably a small amount of additional logic into a massive machine to implement functionality that arguably should have been there from the beginning. The amount of features IBM managed to cram into/bolt onto the 650 is remarkable. The core processor had 42 instructions but after all the peripherals were introduced there were 97 (well, 98, taking this TLE into account), out of a possible 100.

Comment: And it's $25/mo. -- you're **renting** the instruction.  I wonder what happens when you don't want to rent it any more.

Comment: @another-dave No issue, then an IBM field engineer will come and disable it.

Comment: @Raffzahn Weren't 650 systems themselves rented, which included monthly service? So your regular IBM tech would simply have "disable TLE" added to their next work order.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Service doesn't mean they are coming once a month - especially not back then. More likely there was a FE always at site or within short distance. Nonetheless, they wouldn't act on their own, but get a note from sales what to install, activate or deactivate and come accordingly.

Comment: By "install logic" perhaps you mean "flick a switch" or "connect one wire"...

Comment: @user253751, Clipping a diode was one method that they used to enable some optional features. I suppose you'd need a soldering iron and a new diode to disable it again. ISTR hearing about a line printer that had a high-speed option. When the service tech came out to upgrade your low-speed printer, all he did was open a cover, clip one wire, and then button it back up again. On later computers (e.g., some of the 360 models), an optional feature might be enabled by installing different microcode.